# Is there a way to communicate to a AeoTech multisensor over objective c?

Tags: objective-c, z-wave

I'm building my own custom smart home network and am wondering if there is a way to integrate the aeotech multi sensor into an iPad application.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.digiwave.dk/en/programming/an-introduction-to-z-wave-programming-in-c/

You can just use Serial to a Z-Wave stick.

Answer (score 1):

I thought normally you have a Z-wave box (vera/zipato/fibaro/ other).
these are reachable through your wifi, your ipad does not have z-wave connectivity.

usually your box will implement webservices to receive third-party calls.
from then on it is dependant on the apis of your box.